# MQTT connection not being recognised in void loop()

Tags: esp32, adafruit, mqtt

I am trying to publish MPU 9250 readings in the Adafruit IO sending the data from ESP32. The WiFi connection is being established, but the code is not going inside the `if(mqtt.connected())` inside the `void loop()` whereas it's going inside the same command inside the `void setup()`.

I am sure there are no connection issues because once I change `if(mqtt.connected())` to `while(mqtt.connected())` inside `setup()`, code is going inside the `while` loop continuously.

Why is the code not going inside the `if` command and how can this be solved?

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h >
#include <Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h>
#include <MPU9250.h>

#define wifi "********"
#define password "********"
#define server "io.adafruit.com"
#define port 1883
#define username "*******"
#define key "********"

WiFiClient esp;
MPU9250 IMU(Wire,0x68);
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&esp, server, port, username, key);
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish feed = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, username"feeds/accelerodata");

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println("Adafruit MQTT Demo");
  Serial.println("Connecting to");
  Serial.println(wifi);
  WiFi.begin(wifi,password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Connecting...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected");
  Serial.println("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT");
  
  if (mqtt.connect()) {
    Serial.println("MQTT Connected");
  }
} 

void loop () {
  Serial.println("Test line to check if code reaches inside loop");
  delay(1000);

  if (mqtt.connected()) {
    int data=IMU.getAccelX_mss();
    Serial.println("\nSending accelero data");
    Serial.println(data);
    Serial.println("....");
    if (feed.publish(data)) {
      Serial.println("Success");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Fail");
    }
    delay(800);
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe there should be a `/` betweeen the `username` and the `"feeds/..."` portion in your feed definition. I.e.: `Adafruit_MQTT_Publish feed=Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt,username"/feeds/accelerodata");`

Comment: I think it should not matter as long as they are inside "   ". Anyways I tried changing that too...

Comment: It does matter because username and the quoted string form a (longer) single string. Adafruit IO uses the first part of the string (up to the first `/` ) to identify the individual users using their service. The part after the first `/` is used to find the feed you (as an Adafruit IO user) have defined yourself. Look at the examples provided with the Adafruit IO library. They all use the `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you are attempting to use the MQTT connection before it's actually connected.  So your check:

```
if(mqtt.connected())
```

is always FALSE since it's not really connected.  The Adafruit library information here:

[Adafruit MQTT](https://learn.adafruit.com/mqtt-adafruit-io-and-you/intro-to-adafruit-mqtt)

Says to initialize MQTT as:

```
// Function to connect and reconnect as necessary to the MQTT server.
// Should be called in the loop function and it will take care if connecting.
void MQTT_connect() {
  int8_t ret;

  // Stop if already connected.
  if (mqtt.connected()) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("Connecting to MQTT... ");

  while ((ret = mqtt.connect()) != 0) { // connect will return 0 for connected
       Serial.println(mqtt.connectErrorString(ret));
       Serial.println("Retrying MQTT connection in 5 seconds...");
       mqtt.disconnect();
       delay(5000);  // wait 5 seconds
  }
  Serial.println("MQTT Connected!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.. But the connection is not being established. The above function outputs "connection failed". What could be the possible issues? How to troubleshoot the problem

Comment: Did you use the correct username and key? Try some of the example code from the Adafruit IO library.

Comment: If you have a free Adafruit IO account, also take care not to exceed the maximum data rate (30 data points per minute).

Comment: The key is correct.. In-fact the collection frequency was higher initially(higher than 30 points per minute) which I reduced. No improvement in the state though.